# Print html formatted for 8.5x11 paper

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, html, pdf, printing

I have a asp.net mvc 3 view for printing a table. I would like a printable view pop-up.
The resulting HTML print is compatible/formatted for 8.5x11 paper.

The entire page only contains one table, which possible has many rows. Therefore it has many pages, basically.

Export to pdf is fine.

Should I add CSS or other tricks?

```
<body>
<table class="ui-widget">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="ui-widget-content">
                ID
            </td>
            <td class="ui-widget-content">
                PIN
            </td>
            <td class="ui-widget-content">
                First Name
            </td>
            <td class="ui-widget-content">
                Middle Name
            </td>
            <td class="ui-widget-content">
                Last Name
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var r in ViewBag.PINS)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="ui-widget-content">@r.IDNumber
            </td>
            <td class="ui-widget-content">@r.PIN
            </td>
            <td class="ui-widget-content">@r.FirstName
            </td>
            <td class="ui-widget-content">@r.MiddleName
            </td>
            <td class="ui-widget-content">@r.LastName
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about a print.css file? You can style the page then to fit on 8.5x11" (this is the easiest and fastest way). If you need it exactly right then you should use a ASP.net PDF export library.

Comment: see something like this: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml

Comment: The link doesn't have more clues.Then any idea for using pdf?

Comment: For PDF try this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20640/Creating-PDF-Documents-in-ASP-NET